# How do I authenticate users against Active Directory in .NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I desire to authenticate users against Active Directory in my .NET application. How might I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the IIS do it for you :) Set the Authentication of the Site to Integrated Windows authentication and then the user has to logon with his AD User.

Comment: This is best when you can do it, but it's not always an option. Sometimes you have accounts in AD for users on bring your own hardware or at an external site without a direct AD login.